# how to calculate the sum using aggregate, match and group in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this model, and I want to calulate the sum of the amounts with selecting status and eventId.

I use **$aggregate**, **$match** and **$group**

**Model**

```
var moneySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Id:Number,
    Amount: {type: Float},
    Status: Number,
    EventId: Number
}, {
    timestamps: true
}, {
    collection: 'e_money'
});

moneySchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'e_money');
module.exports = mongoose.model('e_money', moneySchema);
```

**Function**

```
getTotalAmount: function (id,callback) {
    var model = require("./Schema/e_money");
    model
        .aggregate([{
            $match: {
                Status: 1,EventId:id
            }
        }, {
            $group:{
                _id: null,
                sum: {
                    $sum: "$Amount"
                }
            }
        }])
        .exec(function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err);
            } else {
                callback(doc);
            }
        })
};
```

But my function returns an empty array. Is there any solution ?

Comment: see this http://excellencenodejsblog.com/mongoose-aggregation-count-group-match-project/

Comment: Yes I used my example from it and i tried also :  [_id: null ], but like I said, it returns an empty array,

Comment: check your schema then,it will have to return correct results

Comment: there is no problem in query you should check data in your database weather it exists for these conditions or not

Comment: I didn't understant this part of query "_id: null", what it does exactly, and should it be changed ?

Comment: I tried this find, and it return some data, but when i use "sum" it didn't return any thing :

 model.find({Status: 1,EventId:id})
                .exec(function (err, doc) {


                    if (err) {

                        callback(err);

                    } else {


                        callback(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc)));


                    }
                })